# Repeatable migrations only within a Release (last update file only) through Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, flyway

We would like to use Flyway in a way where we allow to repeat last migration as long as last schemaVersion it is still not released, so the last db changefile not only would be reexecuted, but if possible, after clearing last changes (so it's not exactly the repeatable migration concept I infer).

Is there any solution or good idea to solve this need? We are using Spring Boot to configure Flyway process.

**EDIT:** So far (thanks to Axel) I found out this two alternatives:

- 0.Increment schema for ANY change, even within a release (avoiding that is the motivation of the question)
- 1.Use spring.flyway.cleanOnValidationError property set to true in any pipeline/deploy prior to the release one   This means if we ever change a versioned script previous to the snapshot one, we'd realize when deploying in the release pipeline
- 2.Work with repeatable migrations (R__) and make some hack to change the name to a versioned migration during release pipeline   Problem:
  CREATES and DROPS are ok, but ALTERS require PL/SQL for the IF
  EXISTS part
- 3.Change db migration provider to one that supports downgrade (the very same flyway documentation says this is usually a problematic idea)

If nobody finds a better solution, I'll acccept Axel's answer

Comment: Is this only for Dev or for other environments as well?

Comment: only for dev, I think, integration stages use always the release

Comment: (so they never face the need for updating a versioned schema file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `flyway.cleanOnValidationError` to `true` to get what you want (or very close anyway): rapid iteration in dev, with automatic schema recreation when a migration changes.

Comment: Interesting feature. This cleans the schema and starts applying all migrations from the beginning if i understand it correctly. But then, how do we guarantee all scripts minus the last one keep the consistency, before we find the error on production?

Comment: I mean, that is exactly the same as recreating the db. what if somebody changes a previous released schema migration script (not the "snapshot" version), and pushes to CI/CD... We would realize of the error later in the pipeline when deploying in non-dev environments

Comment: You only ever enable this in dev. Those types of errors will be found as soon as you hit your CI environment.

Comment: Ah.. I understood by dev you meant an environment that is fail-safe. We deploy in our pipeline a couple of times before releasing, and this deployment must be functional (yet non critical)